# alfresco and ldap configuration

Tags: ldap, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-ldap

I am currently configuring alfresco to use ldap server  for authentication.
I followed the offecial documentation and i updated alfresco-global.properties file but it dosen't work.
i am using alfresco 5.2 and this is my alfresco-global.properties file and the ldap hiarchy.

[image]

```
###############################
## Common Alfresco Properties #
###############################

dir.root=C:/ALFRES~1/alf_data

alfresco.context=alfresco
alfresco.host=127.0.0.1
alfresco.port=8080
alfresco.protocol=http

share.context=share
share.host=127.0.0.1
share.port=8080
share.protocol=http

### database connection properties ###
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.username=alfresco
db.password=admin
db.name=alfresco
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/${db.name}
# Note: your database must also be able to accept at least this many connections.  Please see your database documentation for instructions on how to configure this.
db.pool.max=275
db.pool.validate.query=SELECT 1

# The server mode. Set value here
# UNKNOWN | TEST | BACKUP | PRODUCTION
system.serverMode=UNKNOWN

### FTP Server Configuration ###
ftp.port=21

### RMI registry port for JMX ###
alfresco.rmi.services.port=50500

### External executable locations ###
ooo.exe=C:/ALFRES~1/LIBREO~1/App/libreoffice/program/soffice.exe
ooo.enabled=true
ooo.port=8100
img.root=C:\\alfresco-community\\imagemagick
img.coders=${img.root}\\modules\\coders
img.config=${img.root}
img.gslib=${img.root}\\lib
img.exe=${img.root}\\convert.exe

jodconverter.enabled=false
jodconverter.officeHome=C:/ALFRES~1/LIBREO~1/App/libreoffice
jodconverter.portNumbers=8100

### Initial admin password ###
alfresco_user_store.adminpassword=209c6174da490caeb422f3fa5a7ae634

### E-mail site invitation setting ###
notification.email.siteinvite=false

### License location ###
dir.license.external=C:/ALFRES~1

### Solr indexing ###
index.subsystem.name=solr4
dir.keystore=${dir.root}/keystore
solr.host=localhost
solr.port.ssl=8443

### Allow extended ResultSet processing
security.anyDenyDenies=false

### Smart Folders Config Properties ###
smart.folders.enabled=false

### Remote JMX (Default: disabled) ###
alfresco.jmx.connector.enabled=false


### Remote JMX (Default: disabled) ###
alfresco.jmx.connector.enabled=false


authentication.chain=alfinst:alfrescoNtlm,ldap1:ldap

ntlm.authentication.sso.enabled=false

ldap.authentication.allowGuestLogin=false
ldap.authentication.userNameFormat=%s
ldap.authentication.java.naming.provider.url=ldap://localhost:10389
ldap.authentication.defaultAdministratorUserNames=Administrator,alfresco
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.principal=admin
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.credentials=secret
ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=ou=groups,o=mojo
ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase=ou=users,o=mojo
```

My Log

```
mars 30, 2017 4:05:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFOS: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.32 using APR version 1.5.1.
mars 30, 2017 4:05:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFOS: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
mars 30, 2017 4:05:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFOS: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014)
mars 30, 2017 4:05:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
mars 30, 2017 4:05:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
mars 30, 2017 4:05:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
mars 30, 2017 4:05:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFOS: Initialization processed in 5988 ms
mars 30, 2017 4:05:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFOS: Démarrage du service Catalina
mars 30, 2017 4:05:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFOS: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.x
mars 30, 2017 4:05:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFOS: Déploiement du descripteur de configuration C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\alfresco.xml
mars 30, 2017 4:07:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Error listenerStart
mars 30, 2017 4:07:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Erreur de démarrage du contexte [/alfresco] suite aux erreurs précédentes
mars 30, 2017 4:07:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFOS: Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\alfresco.xml has finished in 108 389 ms
mars 30, 2017 4:07:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFOS: Déploiement du descripteur de configuration C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\share.xml
mars 30, 2017 4:09:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFOS: Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\share.xml has finished in 86 895 ms
mars 30, 2017 4:09:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFOS: Déploiement du descripteur de configuration C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\solr4.xml
mars 30, 2017 4:09:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
AVERTISSEMENT: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
mars 30, 2017 4:09:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFOS: Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\solr4.xml has finished in 34 391 ms
mars 30, 2017 4:09:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFOS: Déploiement de l'archive C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\webapps\ROOT.war de l'application web
mars 30, 2017 4:09:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
AVERTISSEMENT: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'debug' to '100' did not find a matching property.
mars 30, 2017 4:09:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFOS: Deployment of web application archive C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\webapps\ROOT.war has finished in 547 ms
mars 30, 2017 4:09:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFOS: Déploiement de l'archive C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\webapps\_vti_bin.war de l'application web
mars 30, 2017 4:09:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFOS: Deployment of web application archive C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\webapps\_vti_bin.war has finished in 711 ms
mars 30, 2017 4:09:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFOS: Déploiement du répertoire C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\webapps\host-manager de l'application web
mars 30, 2017 4:09:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFOS: Deployment of web application directory C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\webapps\host-manager has finished in 285 ms
mars 30, 2017 4:09:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFOS: Déploiement du répertoire C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\webapps\manager de l'application web
mars 30, 2017 4:09:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFOS: Deployment of web application directory C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\webapps\manager has finished in 244 ms
mars 30, 2017 4:09:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
mars 30, 2017 4:09:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
mars 30, 2017 4:09:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
mars 30, 2017 4:09:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFOS: Server startup in 231821 ms
mars 30, 2017 4:11:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFOS: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
mars 30, 2017 4:11:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFOS: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
mars 30, 2017 4:11:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFOS: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
mars 30, 2017 4:11:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFOS: Arrêt du service Catalina
mars 30, 2017 4:11:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFOS: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
mars 30, 2017 4:11:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFOS: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
mars 30, 2017 4:11:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFOS: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
mars 30, 2017 4:12:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFOS: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.32 using APR version 1.5.1.
mars 30, 2017 4:12:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFOS: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
mars 30, 2017 4:12:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFOS: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014)
mars 30, 2017 4:12:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
mars 30, 2017 4:12:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
mars 30, 2017 4:12:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
mars 30, 2017 4:12:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFOS: Initialization processed in 4101 ms
mars 30, 2017 4:12:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFOS: Démarrage du service Catalina
mars 30, 2017 4:12:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFOS: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.x
mars 30, 2017 4:12:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFOS: Déploiement du descripteur de configuration C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\alfresco.xml
mars 30, 2017 4:15:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFOS: Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\alfresco.xml has finished in 164 795 ms
mars 30, 2017 4:15:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFOS: Déploiement du descripteur de configuration C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\share.xml
mars 30, 2017 4:15:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFOS: Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\share.xml has finished in 34 374 ms
mars 30, 2017 4:15:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFOS: Déploiement du descripteur de configuration C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\solr4.xml
mars 30, 2017 4:15:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
AVERTISSEMENT: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
mars 30, 2017 4:16:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFOS: Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\solr4.xml has finished in 28 614 ms
mars 30, 2017 4:16:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFOS: Déploiement de l'archive C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\webapps\ROOT.war de l'application web
mars 30, 2017 4:16:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
AVERTISSEMENT: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'debug' to '100' did not find a matching property.
mars 30, 2017 4:16:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFOS: Deployment of web application archive C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\webapps\ROOT.war has finished in 479 ms
mars 30, 2017 4:16:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFOS: Déploiement de l'archive C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\webapps\_vti_bin.war de l'application web
mars 30, 2017 4:16:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFOS: Deployment of web application archive C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\webapps\_vti_bin.war has finished in 619 ms
mars 30, 2017 4:16:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFOS: Déploiement du répertoire C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\webapps\host-manager de l'application web
mars 30, 2017 4:16:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFOS: Deployment of web application directory C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\webapps\host-manager has finished in 337 ms
mars 30, 2017 4:16:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFOS: Déploiement du répertoire C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\webapps\manager de l'application web
mars 30, 2017 4:16:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFOS: Deployment of web application directory C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\webapps\manager has finished in 260 ms
mars 30, 2017 4:16:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
mars 30, 2017 4:16:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
mars 30, 2017 4:16:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
mars 30, 2017 4:16:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFOS: Server startup in 229832 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell what the problem is without any error messages or exceptions, but you might want to try adjusting the userNameFormat. For example, instead of %s, it is likely that it needs to be something like:

```
ldap.authentication.userNameFormat=uid=%s,ou=users,o=mojo
```

But, again, it is hard to tell without more info.

Comment: i got no error now but only it use the default users not ldap users

Comment: What do you mean it uses the default users? Do you mean that you can only authenticate with Alfresco-managed users? When you use an LDAP user is anything showing up in the log ($ALFRESCO_HOME/tomcat/logs/catalina.out)?

Comment: Mr Jeff i added the log to the post  so you can check it

Comment: It seems that you have an issue somewhere, judging by your log:
INFOS: Déploiement du descripteur de configuration C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\alfresco.xml
mars 30, 2017 4:07:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Error listenerStart
mars 30, 2017 4:07:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Erreur de démarrage du contexte [/alfresco] suite aux erreurs précédentes

Comment: authentication.chain=alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm,ldap1:ldap-ad
ldap.authentication.userNameFormat=CN=%s,OU=users,O=mojo
ldap.authentication.java.naming.security.authentication=simple
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.principal=CN=Admin,OU=groups

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://geofoss.net/2015/07/10/alfresco-5-0-ldap-authentication/), you need to create ldap properties file inside this path **tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/subsystems/Authentication/ldap/ldap1**

Comment: Putting the properties in alfresco-global.properties also works. You are not required to use the external properties file approach.